# Domain Joining using WMIC command with a batch file

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, wmic

With a batch I was able to successfully join Office Systems on domain but for some reason a few are stuck and I did try the same command with changing `fjoinoptions=2` and `3` but still unable to get them on domain.

```
wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" call joindomainorworkgroup AccountOU="OU=lab;DC=ABClab;DC=local" fjoinoptions=2 name="ABClab.local" username="ABClab\administrator" Password="@@@@@@@"
```

My question is there any way to force join domain?

Also I found out that any system that hits on AD server, A pointer (PTR) is created which needs to be deleted first before retrying force join?

Comment: This would require the domain join log file to pursue. It is located in: %windir%\debug\Netsetup.log. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/troubleshoot-errors-join-computer-to-domain . There must also be testing performed, to determine how the domain join performs using a more traditional method, such as the graphical interface or the Add-Computer PowerShell cmdlet.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-computer?view=powershell-5.1